# How to build a simple bytecode compiler for a stack-based virtual machine?

Tags: compiler-construction, virtual-machine, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, bytecode

suppose I have this simple programming language that contains only these features:

```
// assignments
var a = 2
// if/else statement and condition expression
if a == 2 {
  // print function and strings
  print "a == 2"
} else {
  // halt program with status code
  halt 1
}
```

it's really simple, only a main routine.

I want to generate byte-code for a stack-based virtual machine.
What is the standard way for generating this byte-code?
I've a lexer and parser that build the AST for this program, and now I want to implement the code generator (bytecode compiler) for this program.

Comment: [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is one possible target

Comment: The [Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) contains everything you need, including a description of [The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html), [The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html) and a [Compiling for the Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html) chapter with lots of examples… You should come back when you have *specific* question.

Comment: Thanks for the references.